# Скорость загрузки скрипта

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Как узнать скорость загрузки скрипта в js?

Comment: можно посмотреть в developer tools браузера, обычно на вкладке network(сеть) показывается, сколько заняла времени загрузка того или иного файла

Comment: Что именно? Запрос хита и/или ожидание ответа и/или загрузка файла и/или обработка и/или выполнение? Подобная информация предоставляется в инструментах разработчика, крайне полезном инструменте.

Answer (score 1):

На JS это узнать невозможно, т.к. код JS будет исполнен уже после загрузки.